# Make [unityscript] code samples use lang-js syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Would it be possible to automatically have questions tagged with [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) have their code samples be syntax highlighted with `<!-- language: lang-js -->`?

I see questions tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) get syntax highlighting automatically; could UnityScript get some love too please? UnityScript is similar enough to JavaScript that the JavaScript highlighting works well. I think a lot of my UnityScript edits are to make the code samples look colorful. It would be nice if it was automated :)